# Angularjs http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, oauth

I try to apply in angularjs

```
 POST /api/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
 Host: Myweb.com
 Authorization: Basic Base64(client_id:client_secret)
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=client_credentials
```

Being Like This ..

```
 Var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://Myweb.com/api/oauth/token',
   headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'basic YjBiZGNkZTQtNmE5OS00ZDE4LTg5ZWQtYasdYtek0MzkTWCXy1LTRmOTktNDk0MS1iNDY2LTc2NDysdYdfsdxMzFiYg=='              
   },
   data: { 
           'grant_type':'client_credentials'                
         }     
 }

 $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
              console.log('Success');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
              console.log('Failed');
            });
```

the result always fails, And how to apply correctly, to the grant_type section ??
please help me

Comment: What errors do you get? Is it a JS error, or a server errors?

Comment: There is no js or server error, which I get Failed response.
How to apply to get data?

Comment: Which callback fires, the success or the error callback?

Comment: i get the error callback

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this piece of code

```
var _login = function (loginData) {

        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + 
        loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: 
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {

            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', 
            { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise; 
    };
```

It is actually taken from 
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/784106/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-a

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
   var url="https://Myweb.com/api/oauth/token";    
    var data={ 
               'grant_type':'client_credentials'                
             };  

    $http.post(url,data,{ 
      headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'basic YjBiZGNkZTQtNmE5OS00ZDE4LTg5ZWQtYasdYtek0MzkTWCXy1LTRmOTktNDk0MS1iNDY2LTc2NDysdYdfsdxMzFiYg=='              
       }
    })
   .then(function(success){

   },function(failure){

   });
```